# while using shading in pcolormesh getting error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am facing a problem while using shading for pcolormesh in contour fill plot. As soon as I am give shading as "shading='gouraud'" I am getting this error " TypeError: Dimensions of C (73, 144) are incompatible with X (145) and/or Y (74); see help(pcolormesh)".If anyone can help me in this regard it will be much appreciated. I am also posting my code which I am using.

```
import os
os.environ["PROJ_LIB"] = "C:\\Utilities\\Python\\Anaconda\\Library\\share"; #fixr
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import proplot as plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# --- read netcdf file
dset = xr.open_dataset(r'E:\DATA_SETS\OLR_NCEP_REANALYSIS\olr.daily.1974.2020.nc')
# --- select an area and time (optional)
#dset = dset.sel(lat=slice(15, -60), lon=slice(270, 330))

plot.rc.reso = 'lo'
#--- plotting
f, ax = plot.subplots(ncols=1,figsize=[6.4, 5.0],tight=True,
                  proj='cyl', proj_kw={'lon_0': 0})
# format options
ax.format(land=True, landcolor='mushroom',coast=True, innerborders=False, borders=False,
      labels=True,
      latlim=(0, 30), lonlim=(50, 100),linewidth=1,
      gridlinewidth=0,latlines=5, lonlines=10,
      abc=True, abcloc='ll', abcstyle='(a)')
levels=list(np.arange(120,260,20))
map = ax.pcolormesh(dset['lon'], dset['lat'], dset['olr'][16202, :,:],shading='gouraud',
                  cmap='Blues_r',levels=levels,vmin=np.inf,vmax=np.inf,extend='neither')
f.colorbar(map,length=0.6,loc='b',extendrect=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the dimensions of your coordinates and the 2D variable do not match.

Simplest solution is to use central coordinates of x and y:

```
x = dset['lon'].values()
y = dset['lat'].values()
xnew = 0.5*(x[0:-1]+x[1:])
ynew = 0.5*(y[0:-1]+y[1:])
pcolormesh(xnew,ynew, ...)
```

Comment: I tried as you have given but, it is giving error as 
  "File "<ipython-input-10-be17ddceef91>", line 1, in <module>
    x = dset['lon'].values()

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable"

Comment: Does dset['lon'].values give you the 'lon' values? I am not very good at Pandas/xarray and usually follow the try/error/try... protocol.

Comment: @msi_gerva2 no it doesn't,  without the brackets, in the end, it does. But even though without brackets am getting the same error as mentioned in my question.

Comment: What is the shape of the "xnew" and "ynew" and your variable "dset['olr'][16202, :,:]"?

Comment: @msi_gerva2 "xnew" and "ynew" dimension is 144 and 73, whereas dset becomes (145,74)..

Comment: Well, in the original error message it was C(73,144), now its (145,74)... Just make sure that the data you give to the `ax.pcolormesh` has correct lengths. You can try `xnew = x` and `ynew = y` to debug. Also, keep in mind that dimension/length of y has to match with first dimension of dset and x with second. That is len(x)=144 (143, depending on the correct size of dset) and len(y)=73 (74, depending on the correct size).